# Using SPACY to find the matching company names

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I have two tables for example as shown below:(In actual I have huge data set)

table1:

```
|COMPANY|ADDRESS    |
|BOSCH  |18th main  |
|Infra  |19th main  |
|AB     |21st main  |
```

table2:

```
|COMPANY|ADDRESS    |
|BOSCH  |18th main  |
|Infran |20th main  |
|AB     |21st main  |
```

Now, how can i use SPACY to match the company names in the two tables?
The requirement is, if table1.company matches table2.company then it should result true else false. Same in the case of address also.

OUTPUT:
Matched:

```
BOSCH BOSCH True 
AB    AB    True
```

Unmatched:

```
Infra Infran False
```

need similarly for address also

I have tried going through the below links:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-word-similarity-using-spacy/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-named-entity-recognition-ner-using-spacy/

https://www.machinelearningplus.com/spacy-tutorial-nlp/#stringstohashes

The sample code which i tried using spacy:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
print("Enter two space-separated words")
words = input()
tokens = nlp(words)

for token in tokens:
  # Printing the following attributes of each token.
  # text: the word string, has_vector: if it contains
  # a vector representation in the model, 
  # vector_norm: the algebraic norm of the vector,
  # is_oov: if the word is out of vocabulary.
  print(token.text, token.has_vector, token.vector_norm, token.is_oov)

token1, token2 = tokens[0], tokens[1]
print("Similarity:", token1.similarity(token2))
```

The above code gives me the similarity score between the given input.

can somebody help me out on how to find out the matched company names of table1 in table2 using SPACY? or is there any alternative to find the matched company names and their address in PYTHON??

Comment: spaCy is not the right tool for this. This is a record linking or deduplication problem. Maybe give Dedupe a look. https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe

Comment: Note that spaCy similarity is semantic or meaning based similarity, not spelling or orthographic similarity. So in spaCy "cat" and "kitten" are similar but "infra" and "infran" are not.